# I want a create a config file, using the values of the form

Tags: php, html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <form name="form" method="POST" action="">
         <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> Database </tr>
         <tr><td>Servername:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="servername" value="" ></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Username:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td>Password:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="password" value="" ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td>Database Name:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="dbname" value=""> </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit" ></td</tr>
      </form>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I want a create a php config file, using the values of the form.  I can't understand How can i do this. I'm learner now so please suggest me..

Comment: So what's the question?

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what you are trying to do. Also, what have you tried, what didn't work? From what you said, it sounds as if you want to generate a PHP file based on the form data? That can't be right?

Comment: @Akshay yes you can do everything :D but what you want now ?

Comment: well seeing the form, I think he wants to create a config file, using the values from the form. Is that what you want to achive?

Comment: exactly i want this @MasivuyeCokile

Comment: How can I do this I don't know. Please explain me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to create the config file from the user input, you can create an empty `config.php` file then use `fwrite` and `fopen` to open and write to that file.

```
<?PHP

$errors = "";
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    if (empty($_POST['servername'])) {

        echo "Enter servername";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $servername = $_POST['servername'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['username'])) {

        echo "enter username";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $username = $_POST['username'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['password'])) {

        echo "enter password";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $password = $_POST['password'];
    }

    if (empty($_POST['dbname'])) {

        echo "enter database";
        $errors++;
    } else {

        $dbname = $_POST['dbname'];
    }


    if ($errors <= 0) { // no errors

        $string = '<?php 
$dbhost = "' . $servername . '";
$dbuname = "' . $username. '";
$dbpass = "' . $password . '";
$dbname = "' . $dbname . '";
?>';

        $fp = fopen("config.php", "w");
        if (fwrite($fp, $string)) {

            echo "db created";
        }
        fclose($fp);

    }

}



?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>
</head>
<body>
   <table>
      <form name="form" method="POST" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
         <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"> Database </tr>
         <tr><td>Servername:</td>
         <td><input type="text" name="servername" value="" ></td></tr>
         <tr><td>Username:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="username" value="" ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td>Password:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="password" value="" ></td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td>Database Name:</td>
             <td><input type="text" name="dbname" value="" > </td>
         </tr>
         <tr><td colspan="2" align="center"><input type="submit" name="submit"></td></tr>
      </form>
   </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: After submited that form config file create automatically... I want to this.

Comment: @Akshay yes the config.php file will be created automatically if it does not exist,  given that the file is opened for writing (w) or appending (a). If this answer did help to answer your question, you can upvote and accept the answer

Comment: Yup, And I want that if the file already created then it can delete and create a new file. How its possible.?? @Masivuye Cokile

Comment: @Akshay you don't need to delete the file, the values will be over written by new values

Comment: Yah, I know that.

Comment: so what do you want know? does the solution not work?

Comment: @Akshay if an answer helped to answer your question, you upvote and marke the answer as accepted

Comment: Ya, sure. that code is working..

Answer (score 2):

Simple example:

```
// save to file
$post = json_encode($POST);
file_put_contents('config.txt', $post);

// read from file
$post1 = file_get_contents('config.txt');
$p = json_decode($post1);
// show array
print_r($p);
// show username
echo $p['username'];
```

Or php file

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $php = '<?php
    $user = "'.$_POST['username'].'";
    $pass = "'.$_POST['pass'].'";
    ?>';
    file_put_contents('config.php', $php);
}
```

Comment: OP asked for creating PHP file, not config just stored in text file

Comment: Think .... its simple question

Comment: Now it is with php

Answer (score 1):

If this for config, you can:

- Just create file with `.php` extension and write some data using `file_put_contents` or `fwrite`. You need to write `<?php ?>` tags into file and variables that you want OR
- Copy previous created template and replace dummy values with `preg_replace` or something else. This is IMHO better and flexible solution.